# $P_3$ is unbounded on ($C[0,1], \lVert \cdot \rVert_2$)

Tags: real-analysis, functions, polynomials, normed-spaces

Is it true that $P_3$, the set of all polynomials of degree 3, is unbounded on ($C[0,1], \lVert \cdot \rVert_2$), the set of all continuous function on $[0,1]$? I think it should be true because if $f(x)=a+bx+cx^2+dx^3$, then $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{R}$ can be any real numbers, and so the 2-norm of $f$ will not be bounded.
Please correct me if I'm wrong, maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Looks good to me. You can just set all except $a$ to $0$, too.

Comment: @user251257 If $P_3$ is the set of polynomials with degree _exactly_ $3$ then it is not a subspace; $p(x)=x^3$ and $q(x)=-x^3$ belong to $P_3$, but $p+q$ doesn't.

Comment: @user251257 What? You just added $\{0\}$ so why do you say it is a nonzero subspace? I agree that if you call $P_3=\{q\in\mathbb{R}[x]:\text{deg}p\leq3\}$ then it is indeed a subspace, but if we are talking about the set of polynomials with degree $3$ then it is not a subspace and certainly $0\not\in P_3$.

Comment: @mathbeing my mistake. It's too late here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. To show it just notice that if $p(x)=x^3$ and $a\neq0$ then $ap\in P_3$ and
$$
||ap||_2^2=a^2\int_0^1x^6dx=\frac{a^2}{7}.
$$
So by taking $a$ large enough you can make $||ap||_2$ as large as you want; i.e. $P_3$ is not bounded with $||\cdot||_2$.